# Custom Uninstall not deleting file in .net Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have a settings file created when user run the wpf application.
I have created a custom uninstaller to delete some registry keys related to my app and to delete this setting file. 
But my file is not getting deleted.
Here is the code -

```
 public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);

        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {

                if (registryKey.GetValue("TeachingManagementTool") != null)
                {
                    registryKey.DeleteValue("TeachingManagementTool", true);
                }                    
            }
            if (File.Exists("Setting.ini"))
                File.Delete("Setting.ini");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registry Keys  exception " + ex.Message);
        }

   }
```

I tried Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to get file names and delte it, but it doesnt work. So I checked this line of code works file.Delete(filename). It delets the specified file. So it should delete the file during uninstall as its in the same folder.

At the end I should say- I tried 2-3 different ways to access that file and delete it during uninstallation. but Its not delteting and throwing error some times and sometimes no exception at all.

> The exception was related to Access to SysWOW64\AdvanceInstaller is
>   denied

FYI - MY App has `<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />` already.

I tried solutions available on StackOverflow but its not working So I needed to ask a new question. So please let me know where I am mistaking. I am sure it is something very minor that I might be missing here

Answer (score 0):

***Advanced Installer***: So you are using **Advanced Installer**? In the **Files and Folders view**, select the destination folder in question. In the right pane, right click inside the folder where the file to remove resides. Do you see "**New File Operation**"? Select "**File Removal**" and configure options.

Remember to set the options properly. In particular "Remove On". Select on "Component Uninstall".

[image: File Removal]