# There is a problem with this windows installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I created an installer with WiX and the installation process worked. Then I started working on the uninstall, so I created a bat file that deletes the folders created. However I got this error : "**`There is a problem with this windows installer package. a program required for this install to complete could not be run`**", but now even the installation doesn't work. I undid my work and went back to the previous code when it works but I still get the same problem.

I deleted the files created but there must ba something I am missing.

Comment: Are you on a virtual machine?

Comment: no im usuing my actual pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Custom Action Failure***: That error message indicates a failing custom action. [Logging MSI installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890) - summary of how to do MSI logging and many links for how to interpret log files.

***Remove Folder***: You should not use Custom Actions if you do not need them. [Propaganda against them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779). There are built-in MSI constructs to remove folders and files and also **custom constructs in WiX** and [commercial MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383688/129130) to do so. The crucial question is: do you need to remove the folders? You shouldn't if they are in the user profile - then they are user data.

> [***WiX***: **Removing Files and Folders**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52166404/129130): a write-up on file and folder removal. ***Top Tip*** (as Edd China says): [search github.com for samples](https://github.com/search?q=%3CWix%20%3CRemoveFile%20On%3D%22uninstall%22&type=Code).
>
> - [RemoveFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195919/removing-files-when-uninstalling-wix) (MSI built-in)
> - [RemoveFolderEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477561/129130) (WiX-specific)

***Un-Uninstallable MSI Packages***: Failing custom actions on uninstall can cause packages that seem impossible to remove, but there are many options - [**I would recommend trying Microsoft Fix It**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) first. Here are more options (but fixit should do it):

- [MSI Failure to Uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010020/msi-failure-to-uninstall/55010825#55010825)
- [I screwed up, how can I uninstall my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700646/i-screwed-up-how-can-i-uninstall-my-program/9709964#9709964)

***Virtual Machine***: If you are using a virtual machine for testing, just revert the machine to "undo" the problem instead. Do use virtual machines for testing - particularly if the technology is new for you - of course. Particularly good for testing installation on "clean systems" as well - of course. So you can work out prerequisites.

Comment: but now im back to the original problem , the unistall process does not delete the created files , the problem is that RemoveFolder only deletes empty folders

Comment: Check the RemoveFolderEx construct linked to above. **Be careful!** It is a dangerous construct. Test on a virtual. And what folder is this? Is it generated? Is it installed? What is in there?

Comment: the software that i am working on extracts data so when i install it two folders are created one "PFiles" contains the Dll files required for the software to work ,this folder is in the D: drive and the second folder is the C: drive by default in the programmes (x86) folder its called exctactedData ,the user can put it wherever he wants too, it has the data extracted after the software works , so yeah these are the two fodlers and they both have other folders inside and other files inside

Comment: So PFiles is installed meaning it has the installation files and the extractedData is genereated